# sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer Manual Calculation

Tags: scikit-learn, countvectorizer

How to do manual calculation of CountVectorizer from scikit-learn? Or any source that can help me.

Comment: CountVectorizer just counts the occurences of words in docs and nothing else. Have you checked [the docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#text-feature-extraction)? Here's [my answer 1 with steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49775000/3374996) and [my answer 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42451555/3374996) with simple example.

Comment: oh now i get it, thank you very much sir.

Comment: @VivekKumar It sounds like this is a duplicate. If so, please vote to close as a duplicate.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Countvectorizer just counts the frequency of the each word of whole corpus in the given string.
please check docs for more information.