# n-gram vectorization using TfidfVectorizer

Tags: scikit-learn, tf-idf

I am using `TfidfVectorizer` 
with following parameters:

```
smooth_idf=False, sublinear_tf=False, norm=None, analyzer='word', ngram_range=(1,2)
```

I am vectorizing following text: "red sun, pink **candy. Green** flower."

Here is output of `get_feature_names():`

```
['candy', 'candy green', 'coffee', 'flower', 'green', 'green flower', 'hate', 'icecream', 'like', 'moon', 'pink', 'pink candy', 'red', 'red sun', 'sun', 'sun pink']
```

Since "**candy**" and "**green**" are part of the separate sentences, why is **"candy green"** n-gram created?

Is there a way to prevent creation of n-grams spawning multiple sentences?

Comment: I believe there is no `sentence` in vectorizer. A book is just a collection of series of words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on how you are passing that to `TfidfVectorizer`!

If passed as a single document, `TfidfVectorizer` will only keep words which contain 2 or more alphanumeric characters. Punctuation is completely ignored and always treated as a token separator. So your sentence becomes:

```
['red', 'sun', 'pink', 'candy', 'green', 'flower']
```

Now from these tokens, ngrams are generated.

Since `TfidfVectorizer` is a bag-of-words technique, working on words appearing in a document, it does not keep any information about the structure or order of words in a single document.
If you want them to be treated separately, then you should detect the sentences yourself and pass them as different documents.

Or else, pass your own analyzer and ngram generator to the `TfidfVectorizer`.

For more information on how `TfidfVectorizer` actually works, see my other answer:

- [sklearn TfidfVectorizer : Generate Custom NGrams by not removing stopword in them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49746555/sklearn-tfidfvectorizer-generate-custom-ngrams-by-not-removing-stopword-in-the/49775000#49775000)

Comment: Got it, thanks. So it seem if I want to continue to pass it as file input, I will need to provide my own analyzer.